# SQL Select Query returns NULL when appending string

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table, there 3 columns: `GivenName, FamilyName, MiddleName`. And I have to append all three columns values to output a single column like this

```
Select Upper(GivenName) + FamilyName + Upper(MiddleName) as PersonName.....
```

But if value for any one of the column is null then the whole output is Null.

Any way if I can check if any of the column is null before appending? So that it is not appended and others which are not null gets appended.

But I cannot use 'where GivenName is not null, FamilyName is not null' condition.

I just dont want to append the string which is null. 
For Ex:

```
If GivenName = 'Mark', 
   FamilyName = 'Joseph',
   MiddleName is null
```

Then output should be : MARK Joseph instead of NULL which has not appended MiddleName as it is Null.

(But in SQL it the output is NULL. Try this..

```
declare @FirstName nvarchar(20);
declare @GivenName nvarchar(20);
declare @MiddleName nvarchar(20);
set @FirstName = 'Steve';
set @GivenName = 'Hudson';
set @MiddleName = null;
```

`select Upper(@FirstName) + @GivenName + UPPER(@MiddleName)` => Outputs Null
)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server String Concatenation with Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916791/sql-server-string-concatenation-with-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`isnull`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function to simply output an empty string if the column is null:

`Select Upper(isnull(GivenName, '')) + isnull(FamilyName,'') + Upper(isnull(MiddleName,'')) as PersonName`

I'm not entirely sure you should be doing this in the database ... it seems like a presentation layer concern to me.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
Select COALESCE(Upper(GivenName), '') + COALESCE(FamilyName, ' ') + COALESCE(Upper
(MiddleName), '') as PersonName
```

COALESCE will do a null check on the first parameter. If it is null it returns the second parameter

Comment: +1 for using COALESCE, which complies with the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 0):

An way of doing this kind on concatenation is

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', '') 
               + ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', '') 
                          + ISNULL(LastName, '')
```

And obviously you can use the UPPER and LOWER function where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL(FirstName, ''),ISNULL(MiddleName, ''),ISNULL(LastName, ''))
AS FullName FROM testtable
```

Comment: You need not replace NULLs using CONCAT function. Try this select concat(null,'abc',null).