# SQL Server : concat values

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have 3 columns `SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA`, `SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER` and `SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT` - prefix, the number and ext.

I have created a case where I want to display only the `SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER` if `SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA` and `SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT` are null. Else if they are not null, the output will be "(prefix)number.ext" with parentheses and dot.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA IS NULL AND SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT IS NULL 
           THEN SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER
           ELSE CONCAT('(', SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA, ')', SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER, '.', SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT)
    END
FROM 
    vcc.sprtele;
```

The problem is the output is displayed as the second case on each record: "CONCAT..."

Where is the problem here?

Example: prefix = 650, number = 1234567, ext = 890

- if prefix and ext are null -> 1234567
- if prefix and ext are not null -> (650)1234567.890

If prefix is null and ext is not null -> 1234567.890 and vice versa

Comment: Sample data and desired results would do wonders to communicate what you want to do.

Comment: What do you want to do if one of them is NULL and the other is not?

Comment: Are you sure they are null? Maybe they are just blank? in which case `coalesce(SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA ,'') <> ''` might be what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you have three options in descending order if any of them are null skip that. Perfect opportunity for a COALESCE(step1, step2, step 3, '')

Comment: Here's your duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916791/sql-server-string-concatenation-with-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing 2 cases: 
*if prefix is null and ext is not null* and 
*if ext is null and prefix is not null*.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA IS NULL AND SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT IS NULL THEN SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER
    WHEN SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA IS NULL THEN CONCAT(SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER, '.', SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT)
    WHEN SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT IS NULL THEN CONCAT('(', SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA, ')', SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER)
    ELSE CONCAT('(', SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA, ')', SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER, '.', SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT)
  END
FROM vcc.sprtele;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
COALESCE(CONCAT('(', SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA, ')', SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER, '.', SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT)
        ,CONCAT('(', SPRTELE_PHONE_AREA, ')', SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER
        ,CONCAT( SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER, '.', SPRTELE_PHONE_EXT)
        ,SPRTELE_PHONE_NUMBER,'')
```

COALESCE takes the first non-null value.

Comment: isn't that what you want?

Comment: i have edited my post with an example on how i want the output to be

Comment: @mecnism updated again. You should be able to take it from here

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Prefix VARCHAR(20),
  Num VARCHAR(20),
  Ext VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('1', '11', '111'),
(NULL, '22', '222'),
('3', '33', NULL),
(NULL, '44', NULL);

SELECT CONCAT( IIF(Prefix IS NULL, '', CONCAT('(', Prefix, ')')),
               Num,
               IIF(Ext IS NULL, '', CONCAT('.', Ext))
             ) Results
FROM T
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------+
|  Results  |
+-----------+
| (1)11.111 |
| 22.222    |
| (3)33     |
| 44        |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to put the format characters (parenthesis and period) concatenated to the field value inside the ISNULL() function:

```
;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT  1 AS ExampleNumber,
            '555' AS Prefix,
            '1234567' AS PhoneNumber,
            '999' AS Extension
    UNION
    SELECT  2 AS ExampleNumber,
            NULL AS Prefix,
            '1234567' AS PhoneNumber,
            '999' AS Extension
    UNION
    SELECT  3 AS ExampleNumber,
            '555' AS Prefix,
            '1234567' AS PhoneNumber,
            NULL AS Extension
)

SELECT      ISNULL('(' + d.Prefix + ')', '')
                + ISNULL(d.PhoneNumber, '')
                + ISNULL('.' + d.Extension, '')
FROM        Data d
ORDER BY    d.ExampleNumber
```

Results are:

```
(555)1234567.999
1234567.999
(555)1234567
```

This method can also be used to concatenate, for example, Address1, Address2, and Address3 without gaps, if you concatenate a carriage return + line feed, for multi-line address output.